# Channel Capacity and the Rank of Channel

Tags: quantum-information

Let's say $\Phi$ defined a $d-$dimensional quantum system $I$ is a quantum channel with entanglement-assisted classical capacity no smaller than $\log d$.

This means that there exists a bipartite pure state $\phi_{RI}$ such that
$$(I_R \otimes \Phi_I)(\phi_{RI})$$
has mutual information $I(R:I)$ no smaller than $\log d$. Does  this assumption guarantee that $\Phi$ has rank (as a linear operator defined on the $d^2$-dimensional vector space of Hermitian operators) no smaller than $d$?

It seems nonsensical for $\Phi$ to have rank smaller than $d$ as it can convey $d$- dimensional message (albeit using entanglement in the course), but it is hard to rigorously prove this proposition.